# consul server throw rpc error making call: ACL not found after running for some times

Tags: kubernetes-helm, consul

I have a consul cluster hold on AKS deployed with helm. When I deploy it, it will boot up successfully and running well. However after some times, the cluster will crash and throw the error: `2024-02-01T19:16:01.629Z [WARN]  agent.leaf-certs: handling error in Manager.Notify: error="rpc error making call: ACL not found" index=1`

I think maybe my helm deployment file has something wrong? Here is my helm yaml file:

```
# Enable the Consul Web UI
ui:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer # Expose the Consul UI with a LoadBalancer

# Enable Connect injection
connectInject:
  enabled: true

# Sync Kubernetes services with Consul
syncCatalog:
  enabled: true

# Enable the Consul agent on Kubernetes nodes
client:
  enabled: true
  updateStrategy: |
      type: RollingUpdate
  grpc: true

# Enable DNS on Kubernetes
dns:
  enabled: true


# Set Gossip key
global:
  gossipEncryption:
    key: base64key()
    secretName: consul-gossip-encryption-key
    secretKey: encryptionKey
  acls:
    manageSystemACLs: true
    bootstrapToken:
      secretName: consul-bootstrap-acl-token
      secretKey: token
#    tokens:
#      static:
#      - name: "UI Token"
#        kubernetesSecret:
#          secretName: "consul-ui-token"
#          secretKey: "token"
  tls:
    enabled: true
    verify: false
    enableAutoEncrypt: false
    httpsOnly: false
    caCert:
      secretName: consul-ca-cert
      secretKey: tls.crt
    caKey:
      secretName: consul-ca-key
      secretKey: tls.key

# Configure default settings for services
serviceDefaults:
  protocol: "http"

# Use default settings for the Consul server
server:
#  serverCert:
#    secretName: consul-server-cert
#    secretKey: tls.crt
#  serverKey:
#    secretName: consul-server-cert
#    secretKey: tls.key
  replicas: 3
  bootstrapExpect: 3
  updatePartition: 0
  exposeService:
    enable: true
    type: NodePort
    nodePort:
      https: 8501
      http: 8500
      rpc: 8300
  disruptionBudget:
    enabled: true
    maxUnavailable: 1
```

I tried to manual update the services, however, even after I restarted the servers, it will still have the same error and cannot be booted up after.